# Can I change the prompt in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, command-prompt, prompt

I never work with the GUI and am always inside a terminal (also full screen, so no title bar) set with the -nodesktop -nodisplay option. I also have different servers that I connect to, to run matlab and each of those have different restrictions on hogging computational resources. Since it's hard to remember which server I'm in,especially if I have multiple sessions open, I was wondering if I could change the prompt to display the server name. Try as I might, I couldn't find a resource that explains how to go about it (I'm beginning to think Mathworks doesn't support it). I know, a workaround would be to simply write a function call to `system('hostname')` and put the function in the path, so that it's about as easy as typing `pwd` to find the directory. I'd like to know if there's something more elegant.

Comment: @user564376: What's the reason for not using the IDE?

Comment: i connect to the servers by ssh and do my work there. streaming all the gui through X11 hogs resources (not to mention, jvm), even though I have a very good connection. It's much faster to work from the terminal and print all the figures with 'visible' 'off', push it back to my laptop and view them locally.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a submission on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) that can do this for you: [setPrompt](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26471-setprompt-set-the-command-window-prompt) by [Yair Altman](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/27420). Using it in R2010b, I noticed that I was getting the warning message:

```
Warning: Possible deprecated use of set on a Java callback. 
> In setPrompt at 115
```

Which I was able to suppress using the [`warning`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/warning.html) function like so:

```
warning('off','MATLAB:hg:JavaSetHGProperty');
```

And here's how I changed the prompt to the host name using the [`system`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) function:

```
>> [~,systemString] = system('hostname');
>> setPrompt([deblank(systemString) '>> ']);
P11-4504>>
```

The function [`deblank`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deblank.html) is used to remove trailing whitespace (in this case a newline) from the string.

**NOTE:** The above changes (suppressed warning and modified prompt) don't persist after you quit and restart MATLAB, so you could put the above code in your [startup.m file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) to apply them automatically every time you start a new session.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to apply well to newer versions (MATLAB 2018a), the Altman code now issues a warning about responsiveness. Is there a new way?

Comment: @AlecJacobson: I'd leave a comment on the submission page for `setPrompt` indicating such.

Comment: Although I fully understand why you initially marked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646435/) as a duplicate @gnovice, I think it might be sufficiently different to warrant a duplicate tag removal. I added a short explanation of the differences between the questions, and I also linked to this question - so that users that need it can be redirected. You obviously have more experience here, so I'll leave it in your hands, and I'll respect your decision either way.

Comment: @Lucubrator: The only major difference between the questions is really just what's used as the string value for the prompt (host name versus time stamp), and the help text for Yair's `setPrompt` already goes into some detail for creating time stamps. Honestly, I don't think it warrants a completely new question and answer.

Comment: @gnovice: Sure, I do actually agree about that - if we are talking about the _answers_  (yet I nevertheless think there's value to extracting that information from the help text). I still think the two _questions_ are different however, it just turned out that they had a similar solution.

Comment: One could definitely say that the questions are "related" (I would support a duplicate-tag with such a comment), but certainly not "exact duplicates" - that's potentially misleading for future readers. [_"Distinct questions with identical answers are not identical questions, and thus are not (nessecarily) duplicates."_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/) (my parentheses).

Comment: In any case, what do you think is the best cause of action now? Just keep it as is? I.e. a tag on the newer question as a pointer to the older one, together with the aded quote-block describing the differences. Anything I should change?

Comment: @Lucubrator: I would just keep it as is for now, with the link back to the original. Whether exact or nearly-identical, duplicates generally aren't removed. They are assumed to have value in that they broaden the number of search targets with a slightly different rephrasing of the underlying question.