# How to add a date or timestamp to the Matlab prompt?

Tags: matlab, date, time, command-prompt, prompt

> This question has been marked as a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048889/can-i-change-the-prompt-in-matlab) asking about the possibility of
> displaying the current system hostname in the prompt. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048889/can-i-change-the-prompt-in-matlab/5049114#5049114) to that question successfully uses the same custom prompt,
> called [setPrompt()](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26471-setprompt-set-the-command-window-prompt), as does the accepted answer to this question (see below).
>
> **Please note however:** that question does not talk about
> date/timestamps, nor does the answer give detailed step-for-step
> instructions. The answer below does both of those things and might, or
> might not, therefore be the best-suited answer for you.

It can be useful to know *when* (e.g. "11:32 pm") a Matlab command has been executed. I have been looking for the possibility to show a date/timestamp in the Matlab prompt. I am using Matlab R2017b on Windows 10.

Is that possible, and if so, what are the step-for-step instructions for implementing such a prompt?

Preferably I want it to look like the following:

```
[13:45:57] >> 1
ans =
     1
[13:45:58] >>
```

**Note:** It turns out that it is indeed possible, check the answer (self-written).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As of the R2017b release, it is possible to display command execution timestamps using
>   [setPrompt](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26471),
>   a custom command prompt from the Matlab File Exchange (see instructions below).
>
> For a technical explanation of the code, see the
>   [author's](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/642467-yair-altman)
>   original [blog
>   post](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setprompt-setting-matlab-desktop-prompt)
>   about setPrompt.

---

### Configuring a custom prompt

Configuring a custom prompt is easy and takes only a few minutes.

- Download and extract `setPrompt.m` into your Matlab *path* (find it with the `userpath` command).
- If you want to set the prompt permanently, you can put a call to `setPrompt()` in your `startup.m` file.
- If you haven't configured your startup file, simply go to the Matlab command line and do:

  1. `userpath`
  2. `cd <YOUR_USERPATH>`, (usually `C:\Users\<USER>\Documents\MATLAB`).
  3. `edit startup.m`, click "yes", and add your setPrompt call into the file.

As an example, you can put `setPrompt('<timestamp> ')` in your startup file to get a continuously updated date/timestamp prompt. To get back the default prompt, call setPrompt without arguments.

```
>> setPrompt('<timestamp> ')
<06-Feb-2018 01:00:51> 
<06-Feb-2018 01:00:53> setPrompt()
>>
```

---

To get exactly what I wanted I used `setPrompt('[''['',datestr(now, ''HH:MM:SS''), ''] >> '']')`

```
>>
>> setPrompt('[''['',datestr(now, ''HH:MM:SS''), ''] >> '']')
[13:45:57] >>
[13:45:57] >> 1

ans =

     1

[13:45:58] >>
```